# Keep getting script syntax error, code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to combine the two code snippets but keep getting errors, please help??

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#right-sidebar').stickySidebar({
        sidebarTopMargin: 20,
        footerThreshold: 100
    });
});
```

and

```
if($("#mobiledetector").css("display") != "block") {
    $.stickySidebar(".....);
}
```

I am using bootstrap, wanted my right sidebar to be sticky which I solved with the plugin stickySidebar.js, works excellent. Problem is when you resize the sidebar falls to the left in between the other content, a real mess. I tried to fix it with css so that the plugin is disabled on small screens but cant get it right. Here is the relevant css

```
#mobiledetector {
display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 660px) {
#mobiledetector { 
display:block;
}
}
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: can you provide the combined code?

Comment: Maybe, posting your HTML code will help!

Comment: Code not working at all, keeps getting syntax error

Comment: $.stickysidebarscroll(".....); is $.stickysidebarscroll really there? can you confirm?

Comment: You can post the error snapshot then?

Comment: ohh you missed ". do $.stickysidebarscroll(".....");

Comment: If I onlu use the first snippet, it works fine, the second is to prevent the code from working with small screens but when I try to add it it is not working at all

Comment: $.stickysidebarscroll(".....");   use this you had missed "(double quote)

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { if($("#mobiledetector").css("display") != "block") { $.stickysidebarscroll("....."); } else { $('#right-sidebar').stickySidebar({ ... }); } });`?

Comment: where are your params i.e  `$.stickysidebarscroll("#<id_of_last_element>",{offset: {top: 10, bottom: 200}});`?

Comment: Add the combined code which is giving you the error to your question not in comments. Also you need to close this  `$.stickySidebar(".....);` with proper double quotes like  `$.stickySidebar(".....");`

Comment: Ok Guys I am using bootstrap, wanted my right sidebar to be sticky which I solved with the plugin stickySidebar.js, works excellent. Problem is when you resize the sidebar falls to the left in between the other content, a real mess. I tried to fix it with css sothat the plugin is disabled on small screens but cant get it right. Here is the relevant css   
       #mobiledetector {
 display:none;
 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 660px) {
#mobiledetector { 
display:block;
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code needs a selector

```
 $.stickysidebarscroll(".....);
```

So

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($("#mobiledetector").css("display") != "block") {
        $('#right-sidebar').stickySidebar({
            sidebarTopMargin: 20,
            footerThreshold: 100
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#right-sidebar').stickySidebar({
        sidebarTopMargin: 20,
        footerThreshold: 100
    });
});

if($("#mobiledetector").css("display") != "block") {
   $.stickysidebarscroll("#<id_of_last_element>",{offset: {top: 10, bottom: 200}});
}
```